# getActivity() in fragment returns null. Issue with FragmentPagerAdapter in parent activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity that hosts a viewPager with two fragments. I'm running into an issue where a call to getActivity() in my fragment is returning null after the activity is destroyed and then re-created (I am changing a system setting while my application is paused in the background which causes the activity to be destroyed and then re-created). Here is what my parent activity looks like.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CalculatorPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private final int HISTORY_PAGE_INDEX = 1;
private final int CALCULATOR_PAGE_INDEX = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new CalculatorPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        /**
         * Refreshes the listView in the history fragment whenever the user moves to it.
         * @param position
         */
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            CalculatorPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = (CalculatorPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
            if(position == HISTORY_PAGE_INDEX){
                ((HistoryFragment) fragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(HISTORY_PAGE_INDEX)).refreshHistory();
            }else if(position == CALCULATOR_PAGE_INDEX){
                //((CalculatorFragment) fragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(CALCULATOR_PAGE_INDEX)).refreshCalculator();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class CalculatorPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    HistoryFragment historyFragment;
    CalculatorFragment calculatorFragment;

    public CalculatorPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        historyFragment = new HistoryFragment();
        calculatorFragment = new CalculatorFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position ==0) return calculatorFragment;
        else return historyFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Calculator";
            case 1:
                return "History";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

I've noticed the lifecycle calls of the activity and fragment happen in the following order.

On initial creation (normal)

1. activity.onCreate
2. fragment.onAttach
3. fragment.onCreateView

When I change the system setting that triggers activity destroy and recreation (issue here)

1. activity.onDestroy
2. fragment.onDestroy
3. fragment.onAttach (no parent activity exists?)
4. activity.onCreate
5. fragment.onCreateView

After this happens getActivity from the fragment retuns null. Am I handling my fragments incorrectly in my parent activity?

This is the logcat from the crash that results from trying to use a null getActivity(). This is triggered by the onPageSelected method from the OnPageChangeListener that is attached to my viewpager.

```
11-26 12:56:21.739 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d035425 time:1218086194
11-26 12:56:24.864 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
11-26 12:56:24.864 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.example.keegan.securetipping.HistoryFragment.refreshHistory(HistoryFragment.java:88)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.example.keegan.securetipping.MainActivity$1.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:54)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1794)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:569)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:553)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2102)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8547)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2400)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2093)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2372)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1722)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8742)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4136)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4002)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3693)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3750)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5823)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5797)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5768)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5913)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:195)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
11-26 12:56:24.868 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-26 12:56:24.869 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.keegan.securetipping, PID: 31769
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.keegan.securetipping.HistoryFragment.refreshHistory(HistoryFragment.java:88)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.keegan.securetipping.MainActivity$1.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:54)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1794)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:569)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:553)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2102)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8547)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2400)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2093)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2372)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1722)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8742)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4136)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4002)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3693)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3750)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5823)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5797)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5768)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5913)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:195)
11-26 12:56:24.874 31769-31769/com.example.keegan.securetipping E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Act
```

This is the code bit that is from my HistoryFragment class that throws the exception. I just call getApplicationContext in order to get an error for this example. Normally the error would be thrown in my FetchHistoryEntries AsyncTask.

```
/**
 * Refreshes the listView in the history fragment with data from the history database.
 */
public void refreshHistory(){

    getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    new FetchHistoryEntries(getActivity()).execute();
}
```

My history fragment only contains a listView. This is its XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/history_listview"/>
```

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: It states NPE in history fragment at line no 88 please post the history fragment and layout too.

Comment: Added the pertinent information. Thanks!

Comment: Please post that too your information is not enough to find out the problem, with this bit of code its hard to predict the flow of compiler.

Comment: If my guess is correct you get NPE in this line
getActivity().getApplicationContext(); try after deleting this line

Comment: Yep that's where the error is thrown but  I'm trying to figure out why getActivity is returning null because I need access to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this by switching to a FragmentStatePagerAdapter opposed to just a FragmentPagerAdapter. The state pager adapter makes it easier to save and restore a fragments state which was what my problem was. This gist had a handy example. https://gist.github.com/nesquena/c715c9b22fb873b1d259

Answer (score 0):

When an activity is destroyed, you lose the context that you are using, that's why your application is throwing an exception, because you are calling `getActivity()` after you destroyed activity which throws a null pointer exception, to avoid this you should change your `refreshHistory` to the following:

```
public void refreshHistory(){
    if (isAdded()) {
        getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        new FetchHistoryEntries(getActivity()).execute();
    }
}
```

`isAdded()` return true when the fragment is attached to the activity and the activity is not null.

You should also consider cancelling your AsyncTask when your activity is destroyed, you can do it like the following: First define a global variable of the same type of your AsyncTask like this `FetchHistoryEntries task;` Second, execute your global task like this

```
task = new FetchHistoryEntries(getActivity()).execute;
```

Finally, in your onDestroy overridden method cancel your task like this:

```
if (task != null) {
    task.cancel(true);
}
```

Hope this helps you, good luck

Comment: maybe you meant `(task = new FetchHistoryEntries(getActivity())).execute();`?

Comment: I can avoid the crash but the issue is that if getActivity() is null then I cannot do the actions I need to do to have the fragment function as intended. The fragment that is returned from fragmentPagerAdapter is not attached to the parent activity and I can't figure out why.